# Vertically Center jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used [this script](http://www.stemkoski.com/stupid-simple-jquery-accordion-menu/) to create a jQuery accordion. Check out the [working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hDRMP/).

It works great, except I would like the accordion to be vertically centered on the page. The idea is that as the height of the accordion changes the `DIV` would be constantly realigned to be vertically centered. The accordion would appear to expand from the center of the page, rather then sliding down from the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a method which will center the accordion container and call this method whenever sliding animation is complete as per your logic.

```
function centerIt(){
    var $accordion = $('.accordion');
    $accordion.css('top', ($(window).height() - $accordion.height())/2);
}
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hDRMP/6/

Comment: That works, although it is a bit jumpy. I actually had more success using CSS `vertical-align`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli [small fix to account for long accordions](http://jsfiddle.net/hDRMP/17/).

Comment: It is is jumpy because we have to wait until accordion finishes it animation and expands the content completely. Other alternative is to animate the top along with accordion animation for which you have to find out the height of accordion's active content pane.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Here is my solution using `display: table` and `vertical-align: middle` http://jsfiddle.net/hDRMP/18/